# How to export Dates from Turbo Integrator(IBM cognos TM1) to SQL table

Tags: websphere, cognos-tm1

I want to export System date using TI.
I tried something like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3WiP.png)

I also tried to export the date I can get from TODAY() in TI but when i tired to export it to a SQL table it gave error. I am assuming the reason for that was its format.

Later I also want to export the date of the respective data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the TIMEST function if I clearly understood your issue.
Here is a linked of the IBM doc:`https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD29G_2.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_ref.2.0.0.doc/r_tm1_ref_timst.html`

You may look to others functions in this documentation.
Here is a sample of code to how use it:

```
cTimeStamp = TimSt( Now, '\Y\m\d\h\i\s' );
```

Comment: You can send us what the SQL format expected in your target Data Base ? It could be better to help you.